# /signin-oidc redirect not working openid connect with Keycloak

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

Note -The issue is in my production app which has SSL installed. I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application deployed on Azure web app.
The authentication is done through Keycloak, using OpenID connect. Below is my `Startup.cs` code.

```
AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            // URL of the Keycloak server
            options.Authority = "{keycloak realm url}";
            // Client configured in the Keycloak
            options.ClientId = "{clientid}";

            // For testing we disable https (should be true for production)
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.MetadataAddress = "{keycloak metadata url}"

            // Client secret shared with Keycloak
            options.ClientSecret = "{clientsecret}"
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            // OpenID flow to use
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
        });
```

Once the authentication is done , Redirect URL **https://{webapp}/signin-oidc** gives below Error.
Also it says the "CONNECTION TO THIS SITE IS NOT SECURE" when the url is still https.

**THE ISSUE IS INTERMITTENT. AT TIMES IT WILL REDIRECT BACK TO THE APPLICATION PROPERLY.**

500 ERROR. WEB APP CANNOT HANDLE THIS REQUEST

[image]

**One Pattern observed**
For the first time if i open the application in Incognito mode, user is redirected to the application properly. and for the second time if i open in the normal tab, it will redirect properly. NO ISSUES

For the first time if I open the application in normal tab, it gives error.
Then the subsequent requests in incognito or normal tabs will throw the mentioned error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error in the code . Changed response type from CodeIdToken to IdToken

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the web-app is hosted in Azure has it HTTPS traffic terminated in the cloud infrastructure and then decrypts the traffic and sends it using HTTP to your application.

Meaning that your application only sees HTTP traffic while users on the public internet sees HTTPS traffic?

I think this is the default that HTTPS is terminated in Aure when you use their HTTPS infrastructure.

Comment: I get this in my localhost as well! The issue is intermittent and the same pattern mentioned in the question is followed in local too.

Comment: I would check in the logs produced by ASP.Net core.

Comment: It was an error in the code . Changed response type from CodeIdToken to IdToken